# How can I detect whether a Linux process has been configured as a child subreaper?

Tags: linux

Using `prctl` using the `PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER` flag, it is possible to have proceses declare themselves "child subreapers".

Normally, on "classic" Unix, when a process' parent exits, `init` (PID 1) becomes the process' new parent process. Declaring a process a "child subreaper" means that this process, instead of PID 1, takes that responsibility for any descendants of this process.

The relevant in-kernel information seems to be `signal_struct` with the `is_child_subreaper` and `has_child_subreaper` flags. Is this information exposed to user-space processes other than the affected process, preferably via the proc filesystem?